# Why is following-sibling faster then preceding-sibling if matched data is located behind

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

If I have a list of value in XML:

```
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 8 9 6 8 7 9 8
```

and I am using `preceding-sibling` or `following-sibling` to search the value that more than `5`. I can clearly noticed that `following-sibling` only take 1/4 time of `preceding-sibling`, but in theory them both query all the element, so why not them take the same time? THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is going to depend entirely on what XSLT/XPath processor you are using, and on the details of how its tree model is implemented. It may also depend on exactly what your XPath expression looks like, and on how you are measuring its performance. So you need to give us a lot more detail. (When asking a question on SO, ask yourself "have I given enough information that someone else could reproduce my problem"?)

It's entirely possible that the tree implementation you are using has forwards pointers and no backwards pointer, in which case finding preceding siblings might involve searching forwards from the start.

Saxon's TinyTree implementation doesn't have backwards pointers when a tree is first built, but the first time you use the preceding-sibling axis there is a one-time cost of creating backwards pointers for the whole tree, after which navigation in the forwards and backwards directions should be equally fast.

No doubt other implementations have other tricks designed to make performance faster but less predictable!